# How to add com.google.zxing API to my java project in VSCode?

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on an application, and I need zxing API for generating QR Codes, so I tried adding it to my Project in VS Code however, as soon as I tried importing it into a class, it throws an error com.google.zxing is not accessible. I've already added Maven dependencies in the pom.xml and the jars in the maven dependencies folder, what am I doing wrong?

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.28</version>       
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you tried right-click the pom.xml and select 'Update project'?

Comment: Yup, however it still shows the error...